# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error when trying to run android test

Tags: android, android-testing

> build tools : 23.0.2
>
> gradle : 2.8
>
> android gradle plugin: 1.4.0-beta6

I've tried using various different versions of the tools but with no success. I've also tried disabling the signing configuration but i still get the same error. It was working fine. And then suddenly it just started giving me this error, i've tried `./gradlew uninstallAll` and running it again with no success. Here is the output i see when trying to run the test, where {package} is the package name of the application and {project path}, is just the file system path to the project:

```
Testing started at 12:16 PM ...
Target device: motorola-nexus_6-ZX1G225WRT
Installing APK: /{project path}/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/{package}
Installing {package}
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/{package}"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/{package}
Success


Installing APK: /{project path}/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/{package}.test
Installing {package}.test
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/{package}.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/{package}.test
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]


Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script.
```

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do this

Answer (score -1):

It seems this is related to using square's okhttp mockserver. When removing the dependency everything seems to work fine again, some have indicated that this is related to a bug in the latest build tools